# Need to search through one column of values and if duplicates are found, compare values in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet of over 9,000 rows and 27 columns. In column A is a date. in Column C is an Equipment Number consisting of letters and numbers. (example ITDX5096, ITD6082, ITDX6843)

I need to compare the values in Col C, looking for duplicates. If one or more is found I then need to compare the dates of those rows for duplicate dates

I have sorted Col C alpha. but I am not sure how to do the date comparison without scrolling through the entire sheet line by line. There could be as many as 20-30 of the same Equipment Number all with different dates.

I would really like to color code any duplicates so that I can locate them quickly but that is probably just a wish on my part. What I need is a way to identify the duplicates so I can scroll the sheet and deal with them.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Conditional formatting on duplicates?

Comment: Should be easy to do using COUNTIF(), and maybe also creating a new cell that concatenates column A & C, and then also do a COUNTIF() on that.

Comment: I had a thought and added a column that appended the two columns. I now have the Equipment Number and the date as a string (41203 = 10/21/2012).

Comment: see my answer below, rrumaner. It's in line with what you are thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a multiple step approach, but it will get you want you need:

1. Sort by Equipment Number and Date together.
2. Insert 2 blank columns after Column C
3. Write this formula in the new column D: `=A2&C2`
4. Write this formula in the new column E: `=Countif(D2,D:D)`
5. Filter column E on anything greater than 1

You will then have all your duplicate equipment numbers with the same date.

Comment: Thanks Scott, but that gave me 1/1/1900 in column E. I set the format to general and every row is a 1

Comment: format column E as `Number` or `General` and you will see the number that is there. Right now it's in `Date` format.

Comment: Here is another wrinkle. Now that I see I have no duplicates (there are nothing but 1's), I need to determine if there are any dates within 1 or 2 days plus/minus each other. Is this even possible?

Comment: change the formula in step 4 in my answer to be `=COUNTIFS(C:C,C2,A:A,A2+1)+COUNTIFS(C:C,C2,A:A,A2+2)+COUNTIFS(C:C,C2,A:A,A2-1)+COUNTIFS(C:C,C2,A:A,A2-2)` and then filter on `>= 1` in column E.